# restating of the existing content model - XHTML

Tags: xhtml, dtd

for my is necesary XHTML.

Then this is my DOCTYPE (code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://myweb.com/DTD/prueba.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Cosmos</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml;
charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://myweb.com/graficos/favicon.ico"
type="image/x-icon" />
<style type="text/css">@import url("https://myweb.com/css/style.css");</style>
</head><body>
<div><planet>Jupiter!</planet></div>
</body></html>
```

and the code of "mydtd.tdt" is:

```
<!ELEMENT planet ANY>
<!ENTITY % html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
%html;
```

but validator.w3.org reply:

```
document type does not allow element "planet" here
```

I believe this answer is because the definition of element BODY of corse no't include the element "planet", I go to W3C and they say in https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/dtd_developing.html#sec_E.3.1.

" **In the case of other elements that already have content models defined, the addition of an element would require the restating of the existing content model in addition to myelement.** "

then I could edit my DTD following the instructions from W3C in:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/dtd_developing.html#s_dtd_dev_elems " **Basically, DTD authors should write the element declaration for each element:** "

```
<!ATTLIST %MyModule.myelement.qname;
      myattribute    CDATA    #IMPLIED
      >
```

but really I unknow how fix my DTD for add my element/tag "planet", some help please?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to insert a `<planet>` element in an XML document, you need to tell the DTD where it can be inserted.
Technically this amounts to rewriting the whole DTD - since you need to tell each existing element that it can have new content - but fortunately the XHTML 1.1 DTD is modular, and all you need to do is redefine one of its entities before including it.

Assuming the new element is a phrasing element, insertable wherever things like `<dfn>`, `<cite>` etc can be inserted, we can use the `InlPhras.class` entity to add the new element to.

```
<!ENTITY % InlPhras.class
     "| em | strong | dfn | code | samp | kbd | var | cite | abbr | q | planet " >
```

Do this before including the XHTML 1.1 DTD in your DTD, so your whole file will look like this:

```
<!ENTITY % InlPhras.class
     "| em | strong | dfn | code | samp | kbd | var | cite | abbr | q | planet " >
<!ELEMENT planet ANY>

<!ENTITY % html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
%html;
```

Then it'll work. And validate.

By the way, do you really want `ANY` for a content model in the new element? This means it's legal to put any element inside it, even `<body>` and `<head>`. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, I copy paste your code and result is

*Validation Output: 1 Error*, "Line 8, Column 8: document type does not allow element "planet" here"

what maybe wrong?

Comment: @Stackoverflow How are you testing this? The W3C validator can't check DTDs directly, so you have to 1) put my code in a DTD file and put that in a place where the Validator can find it, and 2) modify the OP's XML to point to the new DTD; then pasting that in works.

Comment: thanks @Mr Lister, you can see the page load fine in browsers: http://unir.team/Mr_Lister/Mr_Lister.php but W3C say something is wrong... we also want use/add the tags **nav**, **list**, **datalist**, etc... how we can add this tags without encloser into <p> or <div>? thanks again DTD: http://unir.team/Mr_Lister/prueba.dtd

Comment: @Stackoverflow Yes, my answer was tailored to the needs of the OP. In your case, it depends on what you want, and it sounds like you just need to use XHTML5, can that be right?

Comment: sure @Mr_Lister, I need write code XHTML but also validate any page from W3C, but I unknow how passed validator using tags **nav**, **datalist**, etc... And some atributes as **autocomplete**, **list**, etc... I visit https://mrlistersir.wordpress.com but I no't find email/phone, you can create chat here to I contact to you? Thanks ( chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new )

Comment: If you don't need to define any new elements (that is, only HTML5 ones), all you need to do is use `<DOCTYPE html>` for a DOCTYPE. No DTD.

Comment: Sure Mr_Lister I also need use my own tags, after of I resolve my problem with **nav**, etc, I need  use my own tags: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp by this I want used my own DTD and serve my pages as XHTML and no HTML5. I need validate all pages in W3C as XHTML but just now I need add the tags HTML5 **nav**, *datalist*, etc... After I need add (validate) my tags **user**, **country**, **suns**, etc... Thanks again